# c# - What does binary representation of uint is like?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to solve a simple question on leetcode.com (https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-1-bits/) and I encounter a strange behavior which is probably my lack of understanding...

My solution to the question in the link is the following:

```
public int HammingWeight(uint n) {
    int sum = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        uint t = n % 10;
        sum += t == 0 ? 0 : 1;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

My solution was to isolate each number and if it's one increase the `sum`. When I ran this on my PC it worked (yes - I know it's not the optimal solution and there are more elegant solutions considering it's binary representation).

But when I tried running in the leetcode editor it returned a wrong answer for the following input (00000000000000000000000000001011).

No real easy way to debug other then printing to the console so I printed the value of `n` when entering the method and got the result of `11` instead of `1011` - on my PC I got `11`. If I take a different solution - one that uses bitwise right shift or calculating mod by 2 then it works even when the printed `n` is still `11`. And I would have expected those solutions to fail as well considering that `n` is "wrong" (different from my PC and the site as described).

Am I missing some knowledge regarding the representation of `uint`? Or binary number in a `uint` variable?

Comment: I wonder whether they allow `return System.Numerics.BitOperations.PopCount(n);`...

Comment: The values in the examples are printed in binary representation. `1011b` is '11'. You should work in base 2 to solve this terrible Kata (40% of down votes).

Comment: @canton7: It yields error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'BitOperations' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Numerics'

Comment: @Orace That's a shame

Comment: @Orace try `System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86.Popcnt.PopCount(...)` instead, if you're on .NET Core 3.1

Comment: @MarcGravell same result. Apparently (https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) they use Mono 5.18.0. I didn't find which .net core version it matches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code appears to be processing it as **base 10** (decimal), but hamming weight is about **base 2** (i.e. binary). So: instead if doing `% 10` and `/= 10`, you should be looking at `% 2` and `/= 2`.

As for what `uint` looks like as binary: *essentially* [like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Binary_counting), but ... the CPU is allowed to lie about where each of the octets actually is (aka "endianness"). The good news is: it doesn't usually expose that lie to you unless you cheat and look under the covers by looking at raw memory. As long as you use regular operators (include bitwise operators): the lie will remain undiscovered.

---

Side note: for binary work that is about checking a bit and shuffling the data down, `& 1` and `>> 1` would usually be preferable to `% 2` and `/ 2`. But as canton7 notes: there are also inbuilt operations for this *specific* scenario which uses the CPU intrinsic instruction when possible (however: using the built-in function doesn't help you increase your understanding!).

Comment: Thanks. From what I've known so far `uint` is unassigned int - an integer number without negatives and therefor can reach a higher (duplicate) number then int. Am I wrong in that? If not, then what makes it act in this case as a base2 number instead of a base10 number?

Comment: @developer82 because computers deal in bits; bits can be either on or off - 1 or 0. Aka binary. The binary representation of, say, 5 - is: 101 (4=on, 2=off, 1=on). Hamming weight is about counting the "on" bits. The 00001011 example means: the number 11 (8+2+1), with hamming weight 3

Comment: Thanks. I understand how binary works. My question is specifically to understand how it works in c#. For instance when I see a method that accepts `uint` I expect to pass a number to it, not the number representation in binary. So according to my current understanding passing `00001010` would be equivalent to the number `1010`. But in the case above it seems to not do that but rather interpenetrate it as binary which evaluates to `10` in this example. So I'm wondering how c# works in that manner.

Comment: @developer82 C# works exactly the same as just about every other programming language here. When you say "passing 00001010", we need to be clear: do you mean "decimal 00001010" (i.e. one thousand and ten), or do you mean "binary 00001010" (i.e. ten)? To C#, `uint` is *just the pure number* (the abstract concept) - without any associated "as a string in binary" / "as a string in decimal", etc; the bit where we have ideas about what that number **looks like** - that is purely in our fleshy imaginations, or in the `ToString()` code. So: what number are you actually testing with here?

Comment: Is there a different way to pass a number vs binary to a `uint` variable?

Comment: @developer82 you mean a "binary literal" like `0b00001010` ? then: yes, you type `0b00001010`; note: requires C# 7 or above

Comment: I see. This was the missing information for me - the passing of an actual binary value. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @developer82 there's no such thing as a "binary value" or "decimal value" - the value is just the value (and a value *has* no associated representation) - it can be *represented* as binary or decimal or hex or base-64 or any of a number of other things, but the *value* is the same any which way. Think of it in terms of dates: "2020-01-21T00:00:00" *represents* the same value as "21st January 2020" *represents* - but neither representation is that *value*

Answer (score 1):

This Kata has a poor writing, in the examples the **Inputs** are printed in binary representation while the **Outputs** are in printed in decimal representation. And there is no clues to help understand that.

`00000000000000000000000000001011b` is `11` (in decimal, 8 + 2 + 1). That is why you get `11` as input for the first test case.

There is no *numbers made of 0s and 1s in base 10 you have to decode as base 2* stuff here.

To solve the Kata, you just need to work in base 2 as you succeed to do and like @MarcGravell explained.

Comment: BTW, `public int HammingWeight(uint n) => (int) (n == 0 ? 0 : HammingWeight(n >> 1) + n%2);` hit to the top 100% in term of performances.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below  code, it will work for you.
Its very simple way to solve.

```
 var result = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        if ((n & 1) == 1) result++;
        n = n >> 1;
    }
    return result;
```